# Adding constraints to subview leading/trailing/top/bottom not working

Tags: uiview, constraints

I'm trying to add a subview which is pinned to the leading/trailing/top/bottom of its superview, but neither view is drawn when I try and activate the constraints.

When I comment out the constraints code, I see the blue view, activating them I just get a black view in the playground.

To help debug this issue I created a playground, but still can't figure out why this is happening:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface


import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class MyView: UIView
{
    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = .blue
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError()
    }
}


// Present the view controller in the Live View window
let myView = MyView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myView


let subview = UIView()
subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
subview.backgroundColor = .red

myView.addSubview(subview)

subview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
subview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.topAnchor).isActive = true
subview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

So setting the frame alone is not enough, the superview must have width and height constraints set to it.